# Making dropdown menu stay after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm currently trying to make my menu stay when you click on the menu, i mean so that the dropdown menu stays after clicking on it. 
That is code i've already tried(Javascript down below), but for some reason it wont work for me in reality. So I'm looking for help now.

Fiddle with style > http://jsfiddle.net/hRxRG/

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xml:lang="sv">
<head>
  <title>Nösnäs</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" />
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="nav-button">Toggle Navigation</button>

<ul class="nav">
<li class="program"><a href="#">Program</a>
<div class="second nav">
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Teknik</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Naturvetenskap</a></li>
<li><a href="#">El</a></li>
</ul></li>
</div>
  <li><a href="#">Nösnäs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Schema</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Matsal</a></li>
   </ul>






</body>
</html>






console.log("hej");

$(".program").on('click',function () {
console.log("hejssss");
                $('li div ul').toggle('.close');
                console.log("hejs");
                $('li div ul').show();

        });
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vCNks/

Comment: @DonJuwe click on submenu and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code is not valid change it as follows :

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="program"><a href="#">Program</a>
   <div class="second nav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Teknik</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Naturvetenskap</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">El</a></li>
     </ul></div></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nösnäs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Schema</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Matsal</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the JS you need to modify for sub menu click event like this :

```
$(".program").on('click',function () {
   $('li div ul').toggle('');
});
$('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

with css check this : http://jsfiddle.net/hRxRG/1/

Comment: The problem tho, when I apply my style nothing works. Look here > http://jsfiddle.net/hRxRG/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, just as I wanted it. However when I copy the code over to my documents, the exact same thing happens, nothing opens when I click the menu. :/ ANy clue what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: import latest jQuery plugin and add js on load of html document like this  : $(document).ready(function(){//ur JS code})

Comment: It works, hurray! Thank you very much Dipali for taking your time, I highly appeciate it! :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this markup:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="program"><a href="#">Program</a></li>
    <div class="secondNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Teknik</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Naturvetenskap</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">El</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">Nösnäs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Schema</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Matsal</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this Javascript:

```
$('li.program').on('click', function() {
    $('.secondNav').toggle();
});
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vCNks/2/)!

Comment: Thanks, however when I apply my style everything just breaks look here > http://jsfiddle.net/hRxRG/